# Read multiple rows from Oracle table

Tags: oracle, powershell

I am trying to read a table in Oracle from PowerShell and want to save them in an ArrayList. The connection is working but reading the any rows after the first doesn't work.

Here's what I'm trying to do.

```
$rows = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
class Table {
    [String] $name
    [String] $type
}

try {
    $oraConn.Open()
    $sql = [string]::Format("select name, type from source_table where type = 'running'")

    $oraCmd = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand($sql, $oraConn)
    $reader = $oraCmd.ExecuteReader()

    #add tables to arraylist
    while ($reader.Read()) {
        $table = New-Object Table
        $table.name = $reader["name"];
        $table.type = $reader["type"];
        [void]$rows.Add($table)
    }
    Write-Host "rows collected"
}
```

My problem is, I only read the first row of the table, how can I tell Oracle to read them all? Would I have to `count`them first and then query for each row?

I check the contents of `$rows` later in the code, it's not really relevant to the question since I know that this part works, so I left it out.
I know that my query returns something because I tried it in Oracle.

Do I need a `foreach` loop? It would make sense but how can I tell Oracle to do that? Would I have to query for each row of the table and set a counter to query only one row at a time?

I hope someone can help me and point me in the right direction, since I'm already trying a long time to get my script working. I got most of the logic for my script, but if I can't load the rows into my list, my logic doesn't help me at all.

Comment: I define `$rows`in the first line of the code. It's an ArrayList.

Comment: My fault. totally overseen. Is there any reason that's defined out of the try block? And why do you use `[string]`'s `format()` Method? (Shouldn't it have at least 2 parameters?)

Comment: No problem, thanks for the code formatting.
I defined it out of it because in my Script I define most of the variables that are used throughout the Script in the starting section.

Comment: I used the `format`method because I have got other blocks, where I have two parameters. I was lazy and simply copied it, not thinking about missing parameters.

Comment: Your code looks good and matches the [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab4kxd8h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Are you sure that this is the exact code you are using and it should return more than one row?

Comment: Yes it is the same exact code, I only changed  the sql and the column names of my table.

The query is working, but it doesn't read any rows after the first one.

Comment: And if you execute the same query with another sql client you get more rows?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code snippet as a some base for an own solution:

```
$cs = 'data source=oradb;user id=/;dba privilege=sysdba'
$oc = new-object oracle.dataaccess.client.oracleconnection $cs
$oc.open()
$cm = new-object oracle.dataaccess.client.oraclecommand
$cm.connection = $oc
$cm.commandtext = "select name, type from source_table where type = 'running'"
$da = new-object oracle.dataaccess.client.oracledataadapter
$da.selectcommand = $cm
$tbl = new-object data.datatable
$da.fill($tbl)
$tbl | %{"$($_.name = $_.type)"}
```